# R- function in lapply with more than 1 parameter

Tags: r, function, lapply

I need to apply an user function to a part of a data.frame. In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124444/r-apply-convert-many-columns-from-numeric-to-factor/34124480?noredirect=1#comment55997663_34124480) I learned to use lapply for this. I have now a function that needs 2 parameters:

```
truncar<-function(tbl, x){if(class(tbl[[x]])=='factor') {
  tbl[,x]=as.character(tbl[[x]])
  tbl[tbl[,x]=='**',x]<-0                  
  tbl[,x]=as.numeric(tbl[[x]])}
  tbl[is.na(tbl[,x]),x]<-0
  y=ifelse(tbl[,x]>0,1,0)
  return(y)}
```

This code works. An example table might be:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(-3:6, '**'), B=-1:9, C=c(-2:7,NA), D=factor(-3:7))
```

And if I apply it to one column each time, I get the desired result:

```
> truncar(df, 'A')
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

But if I try to do this for many variables with lapply I get an error message:

```
factors<-c('A', 'B', 'C')
lapply(df[,factors], truncar)
```

> Error in NextMethod("[[") : argument "x" is missing, with no default

I understand that this might be due to the fact that my function needs 2 parameters. How can I obtain the result for all the variables that are in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want is

```
lapply(factors, function(x) truncar(df, x))
```

This calls the `truncar` function on `df` for each factor in `factors`.